# massive file writes effect on JVM process performance

Tags: java, performance, io

I have a JVM server which is the only process running on a 32 core machine.  The server is doing lots of file IO which seems to be causing a slow down in overall performance.  I'm confused because all the file IO occurs asynchronously on the same thread and doesn't block any other paths in the program.   Shouldn't the file IO only effect one of the cores, and not the overall performance of the server.

Comment: Its hard to pinpoint exact reasons without the implementation shown here. It could be overhead from the asynchronous framework, high virtual memory usage or simply inefficient or malfunctioning code. Without implementation we cannot give you anything more than speculation. If theoretically the implementation is perfect, I/O slowdown can still occur if all threads/cores access the same filesystem/physical medium (though the main handler thread should stay responsive).

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Here are two guesses from the top of my head. Your ram could be getting fragmented which results in a lot of relocations, or your hardware driver may be loading the cpu a lot. Is your filesystem local at all? Are other applications affected? Can you provide further details?